# ASP.net core MVC catch all route serve static file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to make a catch all route serve a static file?

Looking at this http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/

I basically want something like this:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute("spa", "{*url}"); // This should serve SPA index.html
        });
```

So any route that doesn't match an MVC controller will serve up `wwwroot/index.html`

Comment: If you're already in the routing element, you've gone past the point where static files are served in the pipeline. You can create a catch-all controller action that will return the content of the file instead.

Comment: Is there a recommended way of doing that?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: `return File("~/index.html", "text/html");` in the action seems to work fine

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're already in the routing stage, you've gone past the point where static files are served in the pipeline. Your startup will look something like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

...

app.UseMvc(...);
```

The order here is important. So your app will look for static files first, which makes sense from a performance standpoint - no need to run through MVC pipeline if you just want to throw out a static file.

You can create a catch-all controller action that will return the content of the file instead. For example (stealing the code in your comment):

```
public IActionResult Spa()
{
    return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
}
```

Comment: Which `File` class is that you are using? It cannot possibly be `System.IO.FileSystem.File`. Cannot find a good match.

Comment: @Marcus It's not a file class, it's the [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_String_System_String_) method of the controller class.

Comment: I was a jackass, forgot to inherit from `Controller`, that´s why I couldn´t see it. Thx!

Comment: I get `No file provider has been configured to process the supplied file`

Answer (score 39):

I had to make some additions to @DavidG answer. Here is what I ended up with

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}");

   routes.MapRoute("Spa", "{*url}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" });
});
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult Spa()
  {
      return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly running locally, but when I publish to Azure app service, ALL the requests for static files like *.js files always return the index.html file instead of the actual file being requested. Any idea why?

Answer (score 29):

ASP.NET Core catch all routes for Web API and MVC are configured differently

With Web API (`if you're using prefix "api" for all server-side controllers eg. Route("api/[controller"]`):

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => 
{ 
    await next(); 
    var path = context.Request.Path.Value;

    if (!path.StartsWith("/api") && !Path.HasExtension(path)) 
    { 
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; 
        await next(); 
    } 
});            

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseMvc();
```

With MVC (`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices -Version x.y.z`):

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes => 
{ 
    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "default", 
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"); 

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }); 
});
```

Comment: Wonderful! I used your first solution, although I put `UseStaticFiles` before your logic so that static files will be served first and I didn't need `UseDefaultFiles`. More importantly, I had to set path as `context.Request.Path = "/";` and in my HomeController's Index action, serve `File("~/index.html", "text/html");`.

Answer (score 6):

In case you don't want manually specify which routes are for api:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc() // suggestion: you can move all the SPA requests to for example /app/<endpoints_for_the_Spa> and let the mvc return 404 in case <endpoints_for_the_Spa> is not recognized by the backend. This way SPA will not receive index.html

// at this point the request did not hit the api nor any of the files

// return index instead of 404 and let the SPA to take care of displaying the "not found" message
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
    await next();
});
app.UseStaticFiles(); // this will return index.html
```

Comment: This is working fine also in my asp.net-core-3.1 app. I just added the app.Use and 2nd app.UseStaticFiles after app.UseEndpoints.

Comment: Thank for this answer! This was the solution for my SPA when I converted from core 2->3.1 and my oidc callback redirects ended up with 404. With this trick everything is back to normal!

Comment: What is the point of calling `app.UseStaticFiles()` twice? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @flipdoubt I *guess* it's because he's serving the index page once the static pipeline has already run, so he needs to re-call the static pipeline for it to serve the index page.

Comment: @flipdoubt it's just a way to return index.html at all times, as Maxime Morin said.

Answer (score 5):

What I'm using that works well is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaRouteExtensions.MapSpaFallbackRoute`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // Default route for SPA components, excluding paths which appear to be static files (have an extension)
    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
        "spaFallback",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

`HomeController.Index` has the equivalent of your `index.html`.  You can probably route to a static page also.

A bit off topic, but if you also have an API in the same project under an `api` folder you can set a default 404 response for any API routes that don't match:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "apiDefault",
    "api/{*url}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "ApiNotFound" });
```

You would end up with the following behavior:

- `/controller` => No extension, so serve SPA default page from `HomeController.Index` and let SPA handle routing
- `/file.txt` => Extension detected, serve static file
- `/api/controller` => proper API response (use attribute routing or set up another map for the API controllers)
- `/api/non-existent-route` => 404 `NotFound()` returned from `HomeController.ApiNotFound`

In many cases you'll want an API in a separate project, but this is a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

In order to serve `index.html` from `wwwroot` folder the following directives should be added (.Net Core 2).

This allows to serve static files:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

This allows to get default files, e.g. `index.html`:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core 3.1, I've used the following:

### Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

### MyController.cs

```
[HttpGet("{anything}")]
public IActionResult GetSPA()
{
    return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 6, add `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` in your `Program.cs` file.

Here is example code from the ASP.NET Core with React project template:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");  

app.Run();
```