# How to redirect all 404 routes to one central action in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have these requirements:

1. If a controller, and an action are defined, that action should be called for `/controllerName/actionName` path.
2. If nothing is specified, the `DefaultController` and `Index` actions should be called.
3. If `/nonExistingController/nonExistingAction` is the path, the `DefaultController` and the `Index` action should be called.

In other words, I need catch-partial routing, versus this [catch-all routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509386/how-do-i-create-a-catch-all-route-for-single-page-apps-in-asp-net-core-razor-pag).

How should I define my routing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing for custom ASP.NET MVC 404 Error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/routing-for-custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page)

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom middleware for that

```
public class NotFoundMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Actual processing code goes here
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Then register in in Startup class **after** MVC middleware so it handles all requests not served by MVC (exactly the case of not found controller)

```
app.UseMvc();
app.UseMiddleware<NotFoundMiddleware>();
```

Now `http://localhost:5000/nonExistingController/nonExistingAction` gives us `Hello world` response.

**P.S.** If you really want to use controller you can also redirect from this middleware to `DefaultController` with `Moved Permanently` although it would not be very efficient

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Since we have an infrastructure, working with middlewares has proven to be less flexible, than routes. I consider this workaround as the ultimate solution, but before that I prefer to somehow solve this requirement through routing, or another mechanism I might not know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects Extension, 
and you have to specify a root with {0} in it, to pass the status code,
and add "~" caracter to handle every root to this page,

your code will look like this:
in startup

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/yourAction/{0}");
```

and controller

```
[Route("yourAction/{id}")]
public IActionResult yourAction(int id)
{
// you will use this code to display a custom page for every error
Response.StatusCode = id;
return View();
}
```